# Easy way to install zabbix on Amazon linux 2 ami

Tags: zabbix

is there any easy way to install **`zabbix`** on **`amazon linux 2 ami`**? I was following the official documentation but many issues came up.

First, php issue, i was following the installation process similar to cent os but it showed some error showing that rh-php72-mysqlnd and some other packages were not found.

Second, i couldn't create the database for zabbix, it give **`ERROR 1396 (HY000): Operation CREATE USER failed for 'zabbix'@'localhost'`** So i was just curious that is there any easy way to install zabbix on **amazon linux 2 ami** or is there any good alternative for zabbix in amazon linux 2 ami?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should not be using Amazon Linux 2. Use a supported Linux distribution.

Comment: @MichaelHampton thank you for the information. i became hopeless with zabbix. Now i get that, zabbix dont support amazon linux 2. 
Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 0):

I shouldn't have answered this but if someone comes up with this question he or she may know that if they want to install Zabbix on their machine than they should see the supported platforms first for zabbix. Then they should try. If they try to install zabbix on linux machine then at least they should avoid **Amazon Linux** or **Amazon Linux 2** AMI. THanks